# plupload - limit number of selected files

Tags: javascript, upload, limit, plupload

This is the part of code:

```
inprogress = false;

function getid(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}

var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    browse_button : 'link-browse',
    max_file_size : '100mb',
    url : 'site/upload/process.php?dir=<?php echo $uplid; ?>',
    flash_swf_url : 'site/upload/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : 'site/upload/plupload.silverlight.xap',
});
uploader.bind('Init', function(up, params) {
    //$('filelist').innerHTML = "<div>Current runtime: " + params.runtime + "</div>";
});
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    if(uploader.files.length <= 0){
        var element = document.getElementById('standby');
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
    if(up.files.length > 4 || uploader.files.length > 4)
    {
        alert('Only 5 files per upload !');

        return false;
    }
    for (var i in files) {
        getid('filelist').innerHTML += '<div class="item" id="' + files[i].id + '"><div class="name">' + files[i].name + '</div><div onclick="removeme(\''+files[i].id+'\')" id="remove-'+files[i].id+'" class="remove"></div><div class="size">[ ' + plupload.formatSize(files[i].size) + ' ]</div><div class="percent"></div></div>';
    }
});
uploader.bind('UploadFile', function(up, file) {
    getid('submit-form').innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="file-' + file.id + '" value="' + file.name + '" />';
});
uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
    getid(file.id).getElementsByTagName('div')[3].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
});
uploader.bind('StateChanged', function(uploader) {
        if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
         window.location = "./dl/<?php echo $uplid; ?>"
        }
    });
getid('link-upload').onclick = function() {
    if(uploader.files.length < 1){
        alert('Please select files first.');
        return false;
    }
    inprogress = true;
    uploader.start();
    return false;
};
uploader.init();
function removeme(id){
    if(inprogress) return false;
    if(uploader.files.length == 1)
    getid('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="standby"></div>';

    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

    var toremove = '';

    for(var i in uploader.files){
        if(uploader.files[i].id === id){
            toremove = i;
        }
    }
    uploader.files.splice(toremove, 1);
}
```

I can limit of files being uploaded, 
And if I have 4 files selected, and I select 5 more -> it will show error

but if I at first select for example 14 files, they will be shown in "filelist".

How to limit that, or where to put "return false";

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: A side note 5 files equals a length of 5. Your current script will already alert and return when you try to upload a fifth file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand `if(up.files.length > 4 || uploader.files.length > 4)` to `if(up.files.length > 4 || uploader.files.length > 4 || files.length > 4)`.

Answer (score 5):

`- Working for Pupload v2.0`

```
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
    runtimes: 'html5,html4',
    url: 'upload.php',
    max_file_size: '2mb',
    unique_names: false,
    rename: true,
    prevent_duplicates: true,
    init : {
        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
          var max_files = 12;
          plupload.each(files, function(file) {
            if (up.files.length > max_files) {
              alert('You are allowed to add only ' + max_files + ' files.');
              up.removeFile(file);
            }
          });
          if (up.files.length >= max_files) {
            $('#pickfiles').hide('slow');
          }
        },
        FilesRemoved: function(up, files) {
          if (up.files.length < max_files) {
            $('#pickfiles').fadeIn('slow');
          }
        }
      },
    resize : {width : 700, height : 700, quality : 90},
    filters: [
        {
            title: "Image files",
            extensions: "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use max_file_count: 4 option to limit amount files to upload

Answer (score 0):

in reply to Rob W's answer, `up` and `uploader` is the same since it's the uploader instance, hence redundant; and it would be useful to also check `(uploader.files.length + files.length) > 4` in order to check if a couple of incoming files would exceed the 4 when taking the already "registered" files into account (e.g. somebody adds 2 files and then 3 files subsequently).

So in conclusion, I would recommend

```
if(uploader.files.length > 4 || files.length > 4 || (uploader.files.length + files.length) > 4) {
```